# Rexeg exclude words with brackets

Tags: java, regex

I'm searching how to exclude some words matching a syntax.

For example :

I want to remove {g}all{g} words which match {anything} like that.

should output:

I want to remove all words which match like that.

So I want to exclude all words which have brackets and remove brackets too

Thanks for help

Comment: So what's stopping you from reading the regex manual to learn how to correctly build an expression for that? E.g. how to correctly [escape special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) in the regex pattern?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a do-the-work-for-me request without any attempt at finding a solution, also known as *research*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no nesting, this regex should work:

```
\{[^}]+\}
```

As a string, that's `"\\{[^}]+\\}"`.

This is pretty basic, and uses the following:

- `\{` `\}`

  - Escaped `{` and `}`
- `[^}]+`

  - Character class matching one or more characters that aren't `}`